# How can I serve up a file using JAX-RS and then delete it?

Tags: java, file, jax-rs, java-io, temporary-files

I've got a server application that uses JAX-RS. I'm adding an endpoint to it which will retrieve an object (aka a file) from a S3 bucket, save it locally in a temp folder, serve up this file, and then delete it from the temp folder. So one of the methods I'm adding looks something like this:

```
@GET
@Path("/download-file")
public Response downloadFile() {

    File tempFile = null;
    try {
        tempFile = s3FileDownloader.downloadFile();
        Response response = Response.ok(tempFile)
                .header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=myfile.dat")
                .header("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream")
                .build();
        return response;
    } finally {
        if (tempFile != null) {
            tempFile.delete();
        }
    }
}
```

However, that doesn't work, because it seems it's executing the `delete()` method in the finally block before it renders the file. When I hit the endpoint, I get a 500 error from Tomcat stating "the system cannot find the file specified."

If I change it to `tempFile.deleteOnExit()` then it works. However this is not ideal as the server is not meant to ever really exit, besides on reboots which occur very infrequently. How can I get it to render the output before it hits my delete statement? Or is there a better way of going about this?

**UPDATE:** Adding the code I have for my FileDownloader class below, as requested.

```
public class FileDownloader {

    private final AmazonS3Client s3Client;
    private final String bucketName;

    public FileDownloader(AmazonS3Client s3Client, String bucketName) {
        this.s3Client = s3Client;
        this.bucketName = bucketName;
    }

    public File downloadFile(String key) {
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        OutputStream outputStream = null;
        try {
            S3Object data = s3Client.getObject(bucketName, key);
            inputStream = data.getObjectContent();
            File file = File.createTempFile(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdr"), "." + FileNameUtils.getExtension(key));
            outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);

            int read;
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
            while ((read = inputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                outputStream.write(bytes, 0, read);
            }

            return file;

        } catch (AmazonS3Exception|IOException ex) {
            // log the exception
            // throw a custom exception type instead
        } finally {
            try {
                if (inputStream != null) {
                    inputStream.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException) { }
            try {
                if (outputStream != null) {
                    outputStream.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) { }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am highly skeptical that Jax-RS, or any of the raw Servlet based frameworks, is going to let you serve a file out to a client by just giving a File object.  I think you need to take that File object, turn it into some kind of a Stream, grab the response Stream, and stream the bits through yourself, before tempFile.delete().  If you have an actual Temp file, you don't need to delete that either, I believe the JVM deletes on Exit

Comment: Perhaps to check the Responser with getLength() or getStatus() with if, and then delete. The comment above will be recommended as well.

Comment: How large is the file? Can you post the documentation of S3FileDownloader? Because storing what you download to a file looks useless, if you want to delete the file anyway.

Comment: @JBNizet sure thing, I've added the code. Are you suggesting that I can just pass in the InputStream to JAX-RS directly instead of saving it to a file? Also the files will vary in size; some will be small but there is a potential that some might be quite large (i.e. 20+ MB).

Comment: Yes, AFAIK (and as far as I understand the spec), you can pass an InputStream to ok() directly.